# hg annotate -w/-b/-B (whitespace flags) in TortoiseHg

Tags: mercurial, dvcs, tortoisehg

Is there a way, **in TortoiseHg**, to hide whitespace changes when annotating file?
I know that there's an option in hg, but didn't see a support for it in TortoiseHg.
I'm having nightmares, searching for the changeset where the actual change has took place...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set flags in TortoiseHg settings. Open section "Diff and Annotate" and select options you want.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: First set of Ignores are for diff. I guess you were thinking about the second set of ignores (under Annotate:)?

Comment: Sorry, my bad :) Updated my screenshot.